# Why can't I concatenate a binary string with a whitespace? (Like the following example)

Tags: java, file, file-io, whitespace, binary-data

1) This is the class, where my problem occurs:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class ByteFileReader {
    private Converter c = new Converter();

    public void readFile() {

        try {
            FileReader f = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Troy\\Dropbox\\DATAMATIKER\\Programmering Eclipse\\eclipse\\Eclipse Workspace\\2.Semester OS - Binær Streng Læser\\src\\dummyFile.txt");

            for ( int i=0; f.ready(); i++ ) {
                int character = f.read();
                System.out.print( c.toBinaryString( character ) + " " );
            }

            f.close();

        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            System.out.println("Some exception was handled!");
        }

    }

}
```

2) Specifically, in this line:

```
System.out.print( c.toBinaryString( character ) + " " );
```

3) Now, the method toBinaryString() is defined in the following Converter class, which is the c-object:

```
public class Converter {

    public String toBinaryString(int b) {
        return Integer.toBinaryString(b);
    }

    public String toHexadecimalString(int b) {
        return Integer.toHexString(b);
    }

}
```

4) And at last, my Main class with the main method:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ByteFileReader b = new ByteFileReader();

        b.readFile();

    }
}
```

That´s all the code, I have. So I assume it should now be possible to reproduce the exact same situation on another computer in another Eclipse. Just change the file directory of the FileReader to a directory on your own pc. Hope anyone can help!

(NOTE! The wierd part is that if you put a period ".", slash "/" or some other symbol in the problematic text string, it will work fine and print all the binary strings out to the console as it should with the whitespace too.)
I mean like this:

```
System.out.print(c.toBinaryString(character) + ".");
```

(Edit: The above line gives the following output as it should. This is of course from my particular file. The point is that it needs to output binary strings with a concatenation inbetween each)

1001101.1101111.1110010.1100101.1100010.1100001.1110010.1101110.1100101.100000.1101111.1110010.100000

Where as the following line:

```
System.out.print(c.toBinaryString(character) + " ");
```

gives me no output at all!

Comment: And what is the problem exactly? Do you get "weird" output? An error?

Comment: @fge: `c` is not an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem with your code. Your code works fine. We got an issue with the eclipse console view. For some reason it cannot display one long line using the spaces. There are two solutions to solve this problem:

1. Limit your line width within eclipse console

   [image: Use context menu]
   [image: Enable fixed console width]
2. Modfiy your code to do this

   ```
   int length = 0;
   for (int i = 0; f.ready(); i++) {
       int character = f.read();
       String s = c.toBinaryString(character) + " ";

       length += s.length();
       if (length > 80) {
           s += "\n";
           length = 0;
       }
       System.out.print(s);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the console output is buffered. After:

```
System.out.println();
```

Everything is written. So do it at times.

Comment: Or try `System.out.flush()` if you're not interested in having newlines in your output.

Comment: Just tested `System.out.flush()`. Unfortunately it does not solve the problem within eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need it to print it, you can simply concatenate your binary into a large string:

```
String strOut = "";
strOut = strOut + c.toBinaryString( character ) + " "; //concatenate as many times as you want
System.out.println(strOut);
```

Hope it helps